# ObjectMapper: Do not escape

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson

How do I tell Jackson ObjectMapper to 'NOT escape' while parsing a Json object? In other words, return the String 'as is'. For example, my JSON is like this:

`{"field_1":"xyz","field_2":"ABWKJ\/m3ERpLr"}`

After running thru ObjectMapper, field2 value is:"ABWKJ/m3ERpLr", but I want "ABWKJ\/m3ERpLr" 'cause I need to decrypt it & decryption is failing because the '\' backslash is gone.

I tried following:

`MyClass jsonMessage = mapper.readValue(input, MyClass);`

as well as:

`MyClass jsonMessage = mapper.readerFor(MyClass).readValue(input.getBytes());`

But both version change my String in some way. I want it back 'AS IS'. Should I use a different class?

Comment: Funny, but that was an 'edit' issue which I've fixed. Real question is still valid.

Comment: I don't have time to try this myself, but I think this may help you: [CharacterEscapes](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/CharacterEscapes). This [blog article](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2012/08/entry_476.html) talks about its usage a bit. I think the idea is to define a CharacterEscapes that excludes `\\`.

Comment: Note: When I parse using '@Consumes (APPLICATION_JSON)' it works in my WebService. Consumes is from package 'javax.ws.rs' so I know this can be done. I just don't know what code runs when I use '@Consumes'.

Comment: Tried the CharacterEscapes but it's not working for 'reading'. All examples are for writing Json objects.

Answer (score 5):

I know it is a bit late but I had a similar problem.

A solution I found is using JsonRawValue to print the fields raw values.

```
public class MyClass{

    private String myField1;
    private String myField2;

    @JsonRawValue
    public String getMyField1() {
        return myField1;
    }

    @JsonRawValue
    public String getMyField2() {
        return myField2;
    }
}
```

Note that for some reason if you set one attribute as JsonRawValue, you need to add annotations for other attributes as well.

I'm not 100% sure if this is the best solution for the problem but it works, let me know if you find a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

@DilTeam,

@JsonRawValue seems sometimes does not work all the time, I would recommend to take the string and check the token. I had same issue and used as below it works for me.

```
    String responseClone = finalResponse; // finalResponse =Json Response string

    String pinValue = null;

    if(null != responseClone){

        responseClone = responseClone.replace("{", "");
        responseClone = responseClone.replace("}", "");
        responseClone = responseClone.replace("\"", "");

        String[] strNodeSplit = responseClone.split(",");
        LOG.debug("Splited response");


        for (String stringNode : strNodeSplit) {

            int j =0 ;
            String[] strValueSplit = stringNode.split(":");

            for (String strValue : strValueSplit) {

                LOG.debug(j +" Value :" +" "+strValue);
                if(strValue.equalsIgnoreCase("PIN")){
                    pinValue = strValueSplit[++j];
                    LOG.debug("Pin equals value : "+pinValue);
                    break;
                }
                j++;
            }

        }
    }
```